# How to properly redirect to home page and tell javascript to load requested link via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-history

I am trying to implement History api for loading content to prevent reloading whole website when navigating. Modifying the url and pushing to history etc are all pretty straightforward, however I do not understand how the server knows that I want to go to the main page and tell main page to load the content that the link I pasted on browser's address bar points at rather than simply rendering the content without the main page.

For example when I go to `localhost/user/profile` I would normally expect it to load `localhost/user/profile/index.html` file and render only that. What I want is to load `localhost/index.html` and get `localhost/user/profile/index.html` via ajax when I copy paste `localhost/user/profile` on browser's address bar.

To be more specific, [only one of many examples and tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwngGtboldU) I have seen clearly demonstrated and explained how all sub-directories point to the main page, but in that tutorial he used php files instead of directories (e.g: `historyapi/cats.php` instead of `historyapi.cats` only) and he used php's [`require`](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.require.php) function in all these files to always include the main page:

```
<?php
require 'views/header.php';
?>
```

However this is not the common behavior of the websites we all visit everyday and hence I would like to do it without php files and php's include functions, rather to do this all via javascript. How can and should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, there are some things we need to address before going forward.

1. Most often when you go to a website, very few web pages are actually static web pages. Many web pages are dynamic, and *in fact* many URI's are dynamic as well. What this means is that I can go to `localhost/blog/some-title-of-a-post` and be shown the post in question.
2. The above mentioned setup does not happen via javascript in most cases. It occurs through something called "URL Rewriting." Basically what happens is that the server itself is configured to look for URL's that match some pattern and that ***DO NOT*** have a file or directory of the same name. In most cases this is fairly straight forward and you can very quickly Google [Some Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache's Mod_Rewrite.
3. The History API solves a different problem entirely. Some time ago, after AJAX had gotten popular people had come up with a huge issue: The browser has no idea that I've shifted the contents of this page *after* it was loaded. So if you went to `page1.html` and clicked 2 or 3 links that changed different portions of the website, and hit reload you would be greeted by the **original** content that was on `page1.html` Obviously, this became an issue and everyone took to making their own (sometimes hacky) solutions. From the history api I can add in that a user has gone to a page *without them actually having to leave my current page*. This meant that the changes that were made via link clicks could be saved, and seen in the user's browser history (which is super, duper convenient).

### To Answer Your Question (I think)

in summary: I think that the situation you described about the `cats.php` is exactly what I would expect someone to use the history API. Please note that while that link you posted I'm sure is very interesting I do not particularly have an interest in sitting through 20 minutes worth of tutorial. If you would like perhaps a much more detailed example about using the history api, [I found this CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/) post. The [working example](https://css-tricks.com/examples/State/) may give you a bit of insight into how to get what you want working. The biggest thing I want to comment on is that when you click on each of the ghost busters links, it adds in a history object. If you actually go to that URI, the layout looks a little bit different, but this could always be changed based on your needs.

Comment: Ok let me make this more clear: I want to have for example a navigation bar on the left and a bar on top that displays info about the user that's logged in. Like stackoverflow (lets assume it uses files not a database to store content for a moment), when you navigate inside website those bars don't change and when you click on a link to a stackoverflow page, you will still see those bars and there is no php. I am sure they did not include those bars on every single html file they have on their servers. So it should somehow be loading a main page and pulling content from there. (next comment)

Comment: How does it know the link pasted on address bar when I redirect it using apache's configuration? (mod_rewrite or htaccess or anything for that matter)

Comment: I don't know how stack overflow does it (never decided to check), but from just a couple of clicks around the navigation menu with the network mapper on it just looks like they load the page up-- no AJAX. Now I could be totally wrong. To be truthful, they didn't include that bar in every HTML, the included it in the header and footer files which get included server side, and it tends to be done server side because it's a smoother approach.

Comment: <strike>It is actually very very easy to check. Open developer tools and go to network tab. click a bunch of links and you will see requests on timeline do not disappear. If it had been reloading everytime they would have then</strike> sorry sorry it definitely isn't. I misunderstood, ignore this comment

Comment: lol I tried striking through my comment but it doesn't let me after 5 mins. you get the idea

Comment: oh ok, perfect example for this can be facebook. chat section always stay the same

Comment: Again, I am not a developer at facebook but after clicking through some stuff there I would imagine that is done via cookies (to remember which windows were open if you _**hard**_ reload the page, and ajax to load things behind it with the History API coming into play to change the address bar (if you go to a profile, or group). However, if you were to go to that URL (say facebook/groups/1) then the information looks to be gotten mostly from the server's directly (aka no ajax)